# Dealing with KeyError in Python while scraping Reddit data

Tags: python

I ran into a little Problem here. I'm still quite new to python and originally i wanted to do my project, which is about scraping Reddit data, in R. But the RedditAPI wrapper for R is useless so i gave Python a try. I already produced some results but at a certain point my code throws a KeyError and I don't know how to except it.

Here's my code.

```
final = pd.DataFrame()
oldestpost = False
for i in range(100): 
    #making the request with posts older than the previous oldest posts
    res = requests.get("https://oauth.reddit.com/r/europe/hot", headers = headers, params={"limit": 100,"after": oldestpost})

    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    #creating a list with the essential entries from the output
    listdf = list()
    try:
        for post in res.json()['data']['children']:
            listdf.append({
                'subreddit': post['data']['subreddit'],
                'title': post['data']['title'],
                'selftext': post['data']['selftext'],
                'upvote_ratio': post['data']['upvote_ratio'],
                'ups': post['data']['ups'],
                'downs': post['data']['downs'],
                'score': post['data']['score'],
                'url' : post["data"]["url"],
                "num_commments" : post["data"]["num_comments"],
                "date": post["data"]["created"],
                "id" : str(post["kind"]+"_"+post["data"]["id"])})
    except KeyError:
        #???

    len1 = len(listdf)
    indices = range(0,len1)

    #creating a dataframe from the list 
    for index,entry in zip(indices,listdf):
        dftemp = pd.DataFrame(entry,index = [index])
        df1 = pd.concat([df1, dftemp])
    #extracting the id of the last and oldest post 
    oldestpost = df1.loc[len(df1)-1,"id"]
    #add the dataframe to the final product
    final = pd.concat([final,df1])
    time.sleep(2)
```

Unfortunally i cant give the whole code because that would involve private information aubout my Reddit account. The problem is that I recieve after a few iterations a

Keyerror: "id"

So i planned to write an exception that basically says: if it cant find the id the just leave it blank an go on. But i have no idea how. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to do "nothing" in case there is a `KeyError`? A "do nothing" statement in Python is: `pass`

Comment: `pass` if you need to proceed. `break` if you need to stop looping. `continue` (probably what you need) - go to the next iteration.